# How to deleting some old pivot label where are around or similar result of most recent one?

Tags: pivot, pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I would like to delete any previous pivot labels that in range of +-0.3% of the most current result.
For example accouring to pic below, we see...

The most recent pivot is 17.01, and the rule set as deleting label in range +- 0.3% of prevous labels,
so our range would be any label 17.06 > x > 16.96 should delete it.

My question/ How I delete those label that has result where around to the most recent result?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiRHW.png)

Code

```
// Inputs 
res = input(title="resolution", type=input.string, defval="2")
DateDay= input(title="Date Day", type=input.integer, defval=2, minval=1, maxval=31)
leftBars = input(title="Left Bars", type=input.integer, defval=5, minval=1)
rightBars = input(title="Right Bars", type=input.integer, defval=2, minval=1)
src = input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=close)
ShowPivot = input(title="Show Pivot", type=input.bool, defval=true)

// Date Function 
Start_Period= timestamp("GMT-4", year(time), month(time), DateDay, 09, 30, 00)
End_Period= timestamp("GMT-4", year(time), month(time), DateDay, 16, 00, 00)
T = time >= Start_Period and time <= End_Period and not time(timeframe.period, "1600-0930")

// pivot
f() => pivothigh(src, leftBars, rightBars)
ph = security(syminfo.tickerid, res, f())

//Draw label
if T and not na(ph)
    if ShowPivot == true 
        lab_h = label.new(
                  bar_index[rightBars], high, text=tostring(ph,'#.##'), 
                  color=color.white, 
                  textcolor= color.green,
                  style =  label.style_none,
                  yloc = yloc.abovebar)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would entail going back in history to look for bars where a label was created, read its y value and then delete the label if its y value matched your criteria.

There is currently no way to do this reliably, however, because of problems in the way the runtime handles the inspection of past instances of label and line id's. The Pine team is aware of the problem but there is not yet an ETA for the fix.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63394208/11806240) is a similar problematic facing the same issue. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response, it wasn't expecting. Anyway, I'm still working on it, I'm sure there's some way to solve it. Please consider linking the pine with python will be helpful to break up the data and manipulate it. Also, We wanna see TradingView software rather than using a browser will minimize the data latency.

Comment: That's a tall order ) and not currently possible with the architecture.