# Pinescript manage drawn lines by condition

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm struggling with Pinescripts execution model, it seems to be a mix out of statements that get recalculated on every bar and then some not, as I never saw a conditional array creation based on barstate for example. Trying it results in a undefined variable error anyway. So the compiler seems to filter out some statements as global and others get run on every tick.

If someone could spot light on how the pinescript paradigm works it would be helpful. Also I wonder if every line.new call redraws the same line a couple of times and how to avoid this (to max out the max_lines_count)?

I'm trying to implement a simple script. I want to draw horizontal lines for each swing high and if a new high is higher than any old one, I want to switch the style of all old highs to dotted.

[image: Highs marked]

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true, max_lines_count=500)

swings(len)=>
    var os = 0
    
    upper = ta.highest(len)
    lower = ta.lowest(len)

    os := high[len] > upper ? 0 : low[len] < lower ? 1 : os[1]

    top = os == 0 and os[1] != 0 ? high[len] : 0
    btm = os == 1 and os[1] != 1 ? low[len] : 0

    [top, btm]

length = 3
[top, btm] = swings(length)


highs = array.new_line()

if top
    if array.size(highs) > 0 // if I remove this I get an array size is zero exception
        for i = 0 to array.size(highs) - 1
            h = array.get(highs, i)
            if top > line.get_y1(h)
                line.set_style(h, line.style_dotted)

highs.push(line.new(bar_index-length, top, bar_index+1, top, extend=extend.right, color=color.red, width=1))
```

Seems that this was a problem in 2020, is it still? [Pinescript: Recursively delete lines if price crosses above/below them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63368668/pinescript-recursively-delete-lines-if-price-crosses-above-below-them)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the history method proposed in the old stackoverflow post I referenced. I'd still like to know how to use arrays for this, as now I have to use a work around to see which lines were updated.

```
    var ll = line(na)
    if some_condition
        ll := line.new(top_bar_index, top, top_bar_index+1, top, extend=extend.right, color=color.red, width=1)

    for i=0 to 4999
        if not na(ll[i])
            l = ll[i]
            linePrice = line.get_y1(ll[i])
            if linePrice < wick_high and line.get_x2(l) - line.get_x1(l) == 1
                line.set_style(l, line.style_dotted)
```